# Null pointer exception while checking the username password with the database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android and am designing an application which consists a login activity. I am trying a lot but getting java.lang.nullPointerException while checking the username and password field with the sqlite database. Here is the code.

```
public int validateLogin(String s1, String p1) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("select * from login where user =" + "\""+ s1.trim() + "\""+" and password="+ "\""+ p1.trim() + "\"", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        i = c.getCount(); 
        c.close(); 
        return i;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;

}
```

---

```
public class UserPass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText name;
    EditText password;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        EditText password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        Button logit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginb);
        Button registerit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.registerb);
        TextView textt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        logit.setOnClickListener(this);
        registerit.setOnClickListener(this);

       // final String s2="user";
       // final String p2="pass";




    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.loginb:
            //boolean valid=false;
            //try{
            String s1=name.getText().toString();
            String p1=password.getText().toString();
            DBAdapter checkdb=new DBAdapter(UserPass.this);
            checkdb.open();
           // checkdb.check(s1, p1);
            checkdb.validateLogin(s1, p1);
            if(true){
                Toast.makeText(UserPass.this, "logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(UserPass.this, "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            checkdb.close();
            /**}catch(Exception e){
                valid=false;
                String error=e.toString();
                Toast.makeText(UserPass.this, error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }finally{
                if(){
                    Toast.makeText(UserPass.this, "logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;*/
        case R.id.registerb:
             Intent ireg=new Intent(UserPass.this, register.class);
             startActivity(ireg);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

this is the error m getting in log-cat

```
08-04 18:30:48.524: W/KeyCharacterMap(481): No keyboard for id 0
08-04 18:30:48.524: W/KeyCharacterMap(481): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-04 18:30:57.694: W/dalvikvm(481): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.inovawe.userpass.UserPass.onClick(UserPass.java:49)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4121)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4431)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-04 18:30:57.714: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Yup, post your Log-Cat displaying ERROR.

Answer (score 2):

I think your **cursor** remains null, because of using = operator with String comparing.

Try following:

```
c = db.rawQuery("select * from login where user LIKE " + "\""+ s1.trim() + "\""+" and password LIKE "+ "\""+ p1.trim() + "\"", null);
                                                ^^^^                                           ^^^^
                                                ^^^^                                           ^^^^
```

Also **confirm,** is * valid for SQLite?

Comment: thank u for ur response but still m having the trouble. it shows the same error

Comment: Just copy your Log-cat and On this page, click **edit** link below your Question, then you can post your Log-Cat there.

Comment: In Log-Cat, on Roght-Top corner You can see verbose/info/debug/error from it select verbose. And copy WHOLE Log-cat displaying ERROR and paste here.

Comment: log-cat doesnt shows any errors but my application still shows java.lang.nullPointerException

Comment: what is code at Line No:49 in UserPass.java file?? OR POST your UserPass.java file here.